# django serving robots.txt efficiently

Tags: python, django, robots.txt

Here is my current method of serving robots.txt

```
url(r'^robots\.txt/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt',
                                            content_type='text/plain')),
```

I don't think that this is the best way. I think it would be better if it were just a pure
static resource and served statically. But the way my django app is structured is that the static root and all subsequent static files are located in

```
http://my.domain.com/static/stuff-here
```

Any thoughts? I'm amateur at django but

```
 TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt',
                                  content_type='text/plain')
```

looks a lot more resource consuming than just a static call to my static directory which is served on nginx.

Comment: Indeed, it is. Much easier and flexible to deliver robots.txt, or even sitemap.xml via webserver, than coding on Django. Besides, using `TemplateView` for delivering a static file, doesn't seem suitable (it's not a template). And not just coding, but think about all the workflow of code versioning (git....), for something quite easy to serve via webserver. These are my two cents.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes, robots.txt should not be served by Django if the file is static. Try something like this in your Nginx config file:

```
location  /robots.txt {
    alias  /path/to/static/robots.txt;
}
```

See here for more info: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

Same thing applies to the favicon.ico file if you have one.

The equivalent code for Apache config is:

```
Alias /robots.txt /path/to/static/robots.txt
```

Comment: nice solution. but what happens if I don't have access to that file?

Comment: @BlaShadow You don't have access to which file? the robot.txt?

Comment: Why should it be served by Nginx?

Comment: Easier and flexible to deliver + no need to code anything (besides Pull Requets, git workflow, etc.) on Django urls.py.
Just put both files on static folder; run `python manage.py collectstatic`; deliver such files from staticfiles folder on your project via Nginx, Apache, etc.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a late reply, I was looking for similar solution when don't have access to the web server config. So for anyone else looking for a similar solution, I found this page: http://www.techstricks.com/adding-robots-txt-to-your-django-project/

which suggests adding this to your project url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = [
    #.... your project urls
    url(r'^robots.txt', lambda x: HttpResponse("User-Agent: *\nDisallow:", content_type="text/plain"), name="robots_file"),
]
```

which I think should be slightly more efficient that using a template file, although it could make your url rules untidy if need multiple 'Disallow:' options.