# Django server - unable to change robot.txt file

Tags: django, robots.txt

my desired robots.txt rule as follow,

allow all bots,
allow all files to be accessed (DIS ALLOW none),
site map : theoriginalwebsitename.com/sitemap.xml

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: https://www.theoriginalwebsitename.com/sitemap.xml
```

the above code is saved in server but when accessing from outside I get below

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Sitemap: mywebsite/sitemap.xml
```

I wonder why `https://www.theoriginalwebsitename.com/sitemap.xml` not comes in sitemap directory

[image]

Comment: hello @anoop can you explain what exactly your problem is?

Comment: I save exact sitemap link in robot.txt file but when public access the file , they get  mywebsite/sitemap.xml instead of original sitemap link

Comment: hello @anoop if you're using nginx or any proxy server you may check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18424412/14457833)